# Constructing a matrix of order $3\times 3$ such that the limiting matrix also exists in which all the rows are not the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$ A = \left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix} \right] $$ be a matrix where $a_{ij}\in{[0,1]}$, $\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_{ij}=1$ (for $i=1,2,3$), and $a_{ij}\in{(0,1)}$ for $i\neq{j}$. Then how do we construct a matrix $A$ such that $A_{\infty}:=lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}A^n$ exists and $A_{\infty}$ does not have all the rows equal?

Or, how do we construct a square matrix of order bigger than 2 (of non-negative numbers ) having at least two elements in any row are not zero and the sum of each row is 1?

I tried 
$$ 
A = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{matrix} \right] 
$$
And, for this matrix $A_{\infty}$ does not exist. 
If we try 
$$ 
A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \end{matrix} \right] 
$$
Then, $A_{\infty}$ exists but the problem is $A_{\infty}$  has all the rows equal. So, I could not come up with a matrix satisfying both properties.

Answer (score 0):

For your first matrix,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
$A_\infty$ does exist and is equal to 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3\end{bmatrix}.
$$

A matrix with the properties you want does not exist, at least in the first statement of the question. This follows from results related to [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), as the matrices you describe are transition matrices for Markov chains. Specifically, an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $a_{ij} \in[0,1]$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=1$ for each $n$ describes the transition of a Markov chain with $n$ states, where $a_{ij}$ is the probability of moving from state $i$ to state $j$ in a time step. A Markov chain is called *regular* if every entry of $A^k$ is nonzero for some positive integer $k$ (intuitively that it is possible to move between any two states in some number of time steps). Your requirement that $a_{ij}\in(0,1)$ for $i\neq j$ implies that the chain is regular, as it is possible to pass between any two states in one time step if they are different states ($i\neq j$, so $a_{ij}\neq 0$) or two if they are the same state (as you can go from the $i$th state to any other state and then back to the $i$th state).

For every regular Markov chain, it is a theorem that there is a steady state vector i.e. a distribution among the states that remains constant (there are infinitely many, but we get a unique one by insisting that it is a probability vector, i.e. the sum of the entries is $1$). Moreover, each row of $A_\infty = \lim_{k\to\infty} A^k$ is equal to this steady state vector, and hence all the rows of $A_\infty$ coincide.

For the weaker requirement,

> Or, how do we construct a square matrix of order bigger than 2 (of non-negative numbers ) having at least two elements in any row are not zero and the sum of each row is 1?

You can do this by finding a transition matrix for a Markov chain that is not regular. A simple example comes from a disconnected Markov chain (really, two independent Markov chains treated as one). E.g.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can compute that $A^2 = A$ so that $A_\infty = A$.